# Insert ID in the foreach

Tags: php, codeigniter, foreach, codeigniter-3, public

How do I get from the simple insert the ID out and how can I forward it into the Foreach?

Controllers:

```
            public function insert_katogorie()
            {
                $this->Admin_model->insert_katogorie();
                redirect('admin/katogorie/');
            }
```

Model:

```
            public function insert_katogorie($katogorie_attribut = 0)
            {
                $data = array(  'tb_ygo_karten_kategorie_name' => $this->input->post('add_katogorie_name'),
                                );
                $this->db->insert('db_ygo_karten_kategorie', $data);
                foreach ($this->input->post('add_katogorie_attribut') as $katogorie_attribut)
                    {
                        $data = array(  //'tb_ygo_karten_kategorie_attribut_kategorie' => $data,
                                        'tb_ygo_karten_kategorie_attribut_attribut' => $katogorie_attribut,
                                        );
                        $this->db->insert('db_ygo_karten_kategorie_attribut', $data);
                    }
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for the **last_insert_id** method

Your model:

```
public function insert_katogorie($katogorie_attribut = 0)
{
    $data = array(
        'tb_ygo_karten_kategorie_name' => $this->input->post('add_katogorie_name'),
    );

    $this->db->insert('db_ygo_karten_kategorie', $data);
    // returns the last insert id
    $last_insert_id = $this->db->insert_id();

    foreach ($this->input->post('add_katogorie_attribut') as $katogorie_attribut)
    {
        // you can use $last_insert_id inside this block

        $data = array(
            //'tb_ygo_karten_kategorie_attribut_kategorie' => $data,
            'tb_ygo_karten_kategorie_attribut_attribut' => $katogorie_attribut,
        );

        $this->db->insert('db_ygo_karten_kategorie_attribut', $data);
    }

}
```

Reference: https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/helpers.html

Answer (score 0):

Get Your insert id in any variable and pass it in foreach loop

$insert_id = $this->db->insert_id();